# Iterate through query

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to iterate through simple query

```
select a_id, count(ID), TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(`Time`),MAX(`Time`)) 
from data
where a_id = 1
```

This is what I managed to create

```
    DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;

   WHILE counter < 10 
    BEGIN
        
    select a_id, count(ID), TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(`Time`),MAX(`Time`)) 
    from data 
    where a_id = counter
    
     SET counter = counter + 1;
   END
```

But I get:

```
    Error occurred during SQL script execution

Reason:
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=1956) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0' at line 1
```

Comment: Your main query has several sintax/logic errors. If you want to use aggregation functions (`count`), you must use the `group by` clause at the end of your query. Are you clear on your requirements?

Comment: It works, I just need number of rows

Comment: Why do you prefer using programming sintax if you can solve your query directly with sql?

Comment: How can I do that.  I want to iterate in my original query from 'where a_id = 1' to a_id = 565.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `while` loop for this.  You can do this in a single query.  One method is:

```
with recursive ids as (
      select 1 as id
      union all
      select id + 1
      from ids
      where id < 10
     )
select d.a_id, count(*)
       timestampdiff(second, min(d.`Time`), min(d.`Time`)) 
from ids left join
     data d
     on d.a_id = ids.id
order by ids.id;
```

Trying to use a `while` look is troublesome.  Such programming constructs would be in programming blocks.  They are designed for stored procedures, functions, and triggers.

I assume that your code is actually over-simplified, because this probably does what you want:

```
select d.a_id, count(*)
       timestampdiff(second, min(d.`Time`), min(d.`Time`)) 
from data d
where a.id between 1 and 10
group by d.a_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
   DECLARE @counter INT = 0

   WHILE @counter < 10 
   BEGIN
        
    select a_id, count(ID), TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(`Time`),MAX(`Time`)) 
    from data 
    where a_id = @counter
    
    SET @counter = @counter + 1;

   END
```

Comment: the same problem
 '....MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @counter INT = 0' at line 1'

Comment: Not an expert on mariadb... but variables were not declared on this engine like `set @counter = 0`?